# Why my div went position right?

Tags: html, css

I have problem with my div "rating", his position is right, I want to place her on start left.

I can solve using position absolute for div rating, but that's not success solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/uw4srwLy/

HTML

```
<div class="rating">
<span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rating > span:hover:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
}
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
}
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}
.rating > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.1em;
}
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: are you using `direction` intentionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float the rating div to left.

```
.rating {
  direction: rtl;
  float: left;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me, after that div i have a lot off under span elements and div elements, is neccessary to user clear both?
How to change color of hover star, from black to yellow

Comment: Currently I don't see that you need to add clear both. And you can change the color of start to yellow by adding this color property. `.rating > span:hover:before, .rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
  color: #ffd700;
  content: "★";
  position: absolute;
}`

Comment: Always! but not with clear both. Always with a modern clearing classes like https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ It is good practice to clear every floated element. But it is development standards it is not necessary that floated element always create a visual problem.